# Java regular expression creation issue

Tags: java, regex

I have been using regular expressions for a while now but have recently got stuck on creating an expression for this;

'Balance: $[variable here]'

Here are a few examples of what it could be:

```
Balance: $10000
Balance: $1000
Balance: $100
Balance: $10
Balance: $1
Balance: $0.1
Balance: $0.10
Balance: $0.01 // Of course all these could be random numbers like 0.06, 10240 etc...
```

I know it is very simple, but for some reason I just cannot get it right.

All i need is the pattern 'code' that I would need to use, This is driving me crazy! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expression your looking for:

```
Balance: \$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

When using it in Java, you need to escape the backslashes:

```
"Balance: \\$(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)"
```

Comment: This makes a "." compulsory.

Comment: Another question uses this format; "Balance: \\$(\\d+)". Which would be more beneficial to my situation?

Comment: Alright great, looks like we got a winner. Thanks for you're help!

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - `5.`? :P

Comment: @TheLostMind Yeah, I know. We'll all have to quietly admit that [dasblinkenlight's expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25308537/3558960) is the most complete :-)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - I hope mine is comple now :)

Comment: One more thing, I now have the string "pay %username% %number%" is there a way I can separate that to get the username and number using spaces? Thanks!

Comment: @user3794577 - ask a different question for this :P

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your regex is that it tries to match a character that is used by regex language itself, i.e. a metacharacter. Such characters need to be escaped, like this:

```
"Balance: \\$(\\d+(?:[.]\\d+)?)"
```

Note the use of two backslashes, although regex engine requires only one. The second slash is there because the character is part of Java string literal, which also uses backslashes for escaping characters.

Finally, the parentheses around `\\d+` (which means "one or more digit") make a capturing group around the entire number (unlike a non-capturing group `(?:)` around the decimal part).

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex :

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Balance: $10000.003";
        System.out.println(s.matches("Balance: \\$\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$"));
    }
```

O/P:

```
true
```

Other input/ outputs:

"Balance: $10000"; --> true

"Balance: $10000."; --  false

"Balance: $1";  --> true

Comment: Balance: $1 -> false?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Balance: \\$([0-9]*(?:\\.[0-9]*)?)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `Pattern`:

```
String[] input = {
        "Balance: $10000",
        "Balance: $1000",
        "Balance: $100",
        "Balance: $10",
        "Balance: $1",
        "Balance: $0.1",
        "Balance: $0.10",
        "Balance: $0.01"
};
//                            | preceded by (escaped) "$"
//                            |      | any 1 or more digit or dot
//                            |      | 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\$)[\\d.]+");
for (String s: input) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("For input \"%s\", found \"%s\".%n", s, m.group());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
For input "Balance: $10000", found "10000".
For input "Balance: $1000", found "1000".
For input "Balance: $100", found "100".
For input "Balance: $10", found "10".
For input "Balance: $1", found "1".
For input "Balance: $0.1", found "0.1".
For input "Balance: $0.10", found "0.10".
For input "Balance: $0.01", found "0.01".
```